# Deberían aparecer registros dependiendo de los campos seleccionados, pero aparecen repetidos 2 veces por cada fila en la tabla

Tags: php, html, mysql

> Después del select a la bbdd mysql de los campos seleccionados, creo la tabla para ver los datos.

```
<table width="90%" border="1" align="center">
<tr bgcolor="#84B3F9">
<?php
$liencabezado=0; //inicio un contador
foreach ($valorcampos_final as $valorcampos_final[$liencabezado]) {

//$valor_campos contiene un array con el nombre de los campos elegidos que deben aparecer

switch ($valorcampos_final[$liencabezado]){
//switch para que ponga de encabezado dependiendo de los campos seleccionados
case "id":
?>                                  
<td align="center">Registro</td>
<?php                               
break;
case "fecha":
?>                          
<td align="center">Fecha</td>
<?php                           
break;
case "contacto":
?>                          
<td align="center">Contacto</td>
<?php                               
break;
case "asunto":
?>                          
<td align="center">Asunto</td>
<?php                               
break;
case "compromiso":
?>                          
<td align="center">Compromiso</td>
<?php                               
break;
case "comentarios":
?>                          
<td align="center">Comentarios</td>
<?php                               
break;
}
$liencabezado++;
}
?>
</tr>
```

> Hasta aquí sale perfecto, el problema llega en el siguiente código que recorre lo recogido para mostrar lo que quiero y en el orden que quiero. Recojo los datos del select en un array y hago un while para recorerlo, dentro pongo un foreach para que me saque en orden solo los datos que requiero, los saca pero no se para y en la fila repite datos además de sacarlos mal en la repetición, he puesto una imagen con las dos primeras filas.

```
<?php
while($rowdatoslista = $listado_result->fetch_array()) {
//recojo los datos de la base de datos en un array  
//$cuentadatos=count($rowdatoslista);
$lili=0; //inicio contador
?>
<tr> <!-- fila de la tabla que mostrará los datos -->
<?php
foreach ($valorcampos_final as $valorcampos_final[$lili]) {
//$valor_campos contiene un array con el nombre de los campos elegidos que deben aparecer y su orden
switch ($valorcampos_final[$lili]){ //escribe el valor recogido dependiendo del valor del encabezado.
case "id":
?>                      
<td align="center"><?php echo $rowdatoslista [0];?></td>
<?php
break;
case "fecha":
?>                      
<td align="center"><?php echo $rowdatoslista [1];?></td>
<?php
break;
case "contacto":
?>                      
<td align="center"><?php echo $rowdatoslista [2];?></td>
<?php
break;
case "asunto":
?>                      
<td align="center"><?php echo $rowdatoslista [3];?></td>
<?php
break;
case "compromiso":
?>                      
<td align="center"><?php echo $rowdatoslista [4];?></td>
<?php
break;
case "comentarios":
?>                      
<td align="center"><?php echo $rowdatoslista [5];?></td>    
<?php
break;
} //cierro el switch
} //cierro el foreach
?>
</tr>
<?php
$lili++;
} //cierro el while
?>
</table>
```

> Lo que aparece en la tabla en pantalla es que las primeras 4 columnas las hace bien, no debería salir nada más pero si sale, además duplicado y si hay más registros, continúa igual, solo quiero que aparezca 1 vez y con su encabezado. Ayuda por favor, gracias de antemano.
> [image]

Comment: De donde sale la variable `$valorcampos_final`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que al usar `fetch_array()`, estarías obteniendo dos veces los mismos datos, como array asociativo y como array numérico, tal y como dice [la documentación en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

Para evitar esto, haz una lectura como se hace habitualmente, solamente con el `while` y usando [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), que es más espícifico, porque sólo te obtiene un array asociativo.

Además, tanto el `foreach`, como el bloque `switch ... case` no son necesarios aquí.

De este modo debería funcionar. Lo he hecho todo dentro de un bloque PHP, concatenado en la variable `$table`. Así el código es más limpio, sin confusas mezclas de bloques PHP y HTML.

```
<?php
    #Declaramos una variable para concatenar toda la tabla
    $table='<table width="90%" border="1" align="center">';
    #Para verificar la primera fila
    $isFirst=true;
    #Usamo un método de lectura más especifico: fetch_assoc
    while($row = $listado_result->fetch_assoc()) {
        if($isFirst) {
            #Obtenemos sólo una vez los nombres de las columnas
            #y los usamos para declarar el encabezado de la tabla
            $columns=array_keys($row);
            $table.='<thead>';
            $table.='<tr bgcolor="#84B3F9">';
            foreach ($columns as $column) {
                #Esto es para cambiar el nombre de id por Registro
                #Otra alternativa sería usar un alias en la instrucción SELECT de SQL
                $th=$column==='id' ? 'Registro' : ucfirst($column);
                    $table.=sprintf('<th align="center">%s</th>',$th);                          
            }
            $table.='</tr>';
            #Cerramos sección thead y abrimos el tbody
            $table.='</thead>';
            $table.='<tbody>';
        }
        $isFirst=false;
        $table.='<tr>';
        $table.=sprintf('<td align="center">%s</td>',$row['id']);
        $table.=sprintf('<td align="center">%s</td>',$row['fecha']);
        $table.=sprintf('<td align="center">%s</td>',$row['contacto']);
        $table.=sprintf('<td align="center">%s</td>',$row['asunto']);
        $table.=sprintf('<td align="center">%s</td>',$row['compromiso']);
        $table.=sprintf('<td align="center">%s</td>',$row['comentarios']);
        $table.='</tr>';
    }
    #Fuera del while, cerramos el tbody y la tabla
    $table.='</tbody>';
    $table.='</table>';
    #Imprimimos la tabla
    echo $table;
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió tu alternativa, la he adecuado a las necesidades que tengo y ya funciona todo perfectamente.

Comment: @Alberto, considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada si ha servido como solución a tu problema. Así la pregunta no aparece sin resolver y podrá servir a futuros usuarios.